# Including foreign keys in lazy loading

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

So I've just changed my foreign key properties to lazy loading using the *virtual* keyword.

In my entity SupportTicket I got a foreign key reference to UserProfile:

```
[Required]
public virtual UserProfile Owner { get; set; }
```

My Find method looks the following:

```
public static SupportTicket Find(int id)
{
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        SupportTicket ticket = db.SupportTickets.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return ticket;
    }
}
```

My issue is the fact that whenever I get a SupportTicket from the Find method, I cannot access the UserProfile of the SupportTicket since I'm outside the databasecontext.

I've not used lazy loading before so am I supposed to Include() every single foreign key in an entity?

Comment: Yes, lazy loading only works within the life scope of a context. Whatever data you need outside its scope should be fetched by eager loading (`Include`).

Answer (score 0):

```
public static SupportTicket Find(int id)
{
    using (DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        SupportTicket ticket = db.SupportTickets.Include("Owner").SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        // or SupportTicket ticket = db.SupportTickets.Include(st => st.Owner).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
        return ticket;
    }
}
```